# Where is the Output for Proguard's -whyareyoukeeping?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, proguard, m2eclipse

I am using Eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1 build id 20140925-1800) with M2E for Maven.  I would like to know why `a.company.Clazz` is being kept.  I added `<option>-whyareyoukeeping class a.company.Clazz</option>` to the configuration (see below).  The Eclipse Console shows the output (see below).  The execution pauses at `Explaining why classes and class members are being kept...` but nothing is output to the console.

I used [Sysinternal's Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see if any output is going to a file.  I see output being written to `...\target\proguard_seeds.txt` and `...\target\glass.jar` but neither of these contains the reason for keeping `a.company.Clazz`.

**Configuration**

...

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
        <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <proguardVersion>5.0</proguardVersion>
          <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
          <outjar>glass.jar</outjar>
          <includeDependency>true</includeDependency>
          <obfuscate>false</obfuscate>
          <options>
            <option>-verbose</option>
            <option>-whyareyoukeeping class a.company.Clazz</option>
            <option>-dontnote</option>
            <option>-dontoptimize</option>
            ...
          </options>
          ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

...

**Output**

...

```
 [proguard] Printing kept classes, fields, and methods...
 [proguard] Shrinking...
 [proguard] Explaining why classes and class members are being kept...
 [proguard] 
 [proguard] Removing unused program classes and class elements...
 [proguard]   Original number of program classes: 1988
 [proguard]   Final number of program classes:    136
 [proguard] Inlining subroutines...
 [proguard] Preverifying...
 [proguard] Writing output...
```

...

Comment: check PG output ... http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html then, if you can, run a build from the command line so that you can go thru these files to find out more about PG internals

Answer (score 1):

Proguard won't output anything if the class is not kept or if the class doesn't even exist.